# find all elements with specfic class by selemium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im just trying to recieve all `a` tags of a page. it made me crazy.
I do all tries but it doesnt work.
this is my code

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(
    'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3824897854&distance=25&f_E=1%2C2&f_TPR=r604800&f_WT=2&geoId=102221843&keywords=django%20developer&origin=JOB_SEARCH_PAGE_JOB_FILTER&refresh=true')
time.sleep(5)
i = 0
while i < 3:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
    time.sleep(5)
    i += 1
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'ember-view job-card-container__link job-card-list__title')]")
print(jobs)
for job in jobs:
    print('1')
    text = job.get_attribute('label')
    if 'django developer' in text:
        print(text)
time.sleep(7)
```

I tried all ways with **contains** , with ** out contains**, with **xpath**,**css_selector**,
they dont work. **print(jobs)** returns me empty list.

Comment: I can't see such classname on the UI. what are you trying to fetch? Job title?

Comment: If you want all a tags, you must try this: driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")

Comment: I want to display a list of jobs **a** tag. to check if 'django developer ' is in the **a** tags *label* . then i would to add *href* of **a** tag to another list. but It cant recognize the **xpath**!

Comment: no i dont want all **a** tags, because it may had extra a tag that i dont need